# testNg Factory, DataProvider reading from excel sheet, tests pass only with instance with last row parameters, others get NPE

Tags: selenium, factory

I am using factory with data provider reading my data from an excel sheet. The issue is that my tests are passing when the last row from the excel sheet is provided through data providers. Preceding rows are giving me NPE.

I am pasting my code here. Thanks for taking a look.

Here is my factory class:

```
//Factory test class

public class testFactory {

    @Factory(dataProviderClass=dataProvider.MyDataProvider.class,dataProvider="userDataProvider")
    public Object[] factoryMethod(String email,String password,String firstName, String lastName) {

        TestFaceBookUsingExcelSheetAsDataProvider instance = new TestFaceBookUsingExcelSheetAsDataProvider(email,password,firstName, lastName);
        return new Object[] { instance };
    }

}
```

This is my data provider class

```
//Data Provider class

    public class MyDataProvider {

        @DataProvider(name = "userDataProvider")
        public static Object[][] getUserData() {
                return ExcelUtils.fileDataProvider("user");//TODO: currently this value is not in use, hard coded in method
            }

    }
```

Here is the method which my data provider class method is calling to read data from excel sheet

```
//Utility Class's helper method to read test data from excel sheet

//@DataProvider(name = "fileDataProvider")
public static Object[][] fileDataProvider(String sheetName) { //TODO: sheetname
    try {
        //ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(Constant.Path_TestData + Constant.File_TestData,"user");

        System.out.println(Constant.Path_TestData + Constant.File_TestData); //TODO
        //XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(Constant.Path_TestData + Constant.File_TestData);

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook("<path_to_file>\\TestData.xlsx");

        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("user");

        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> rowdata = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

        boolean isHeader = true;

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            ArrayList<String> columndata = new ArrayList<String>();
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                if (row.getRowNum() > 0) { // To filter column headings

                    isHeader = false;

                        if(cell.getCellType() == org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                            columndata.add(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "");
                        } else if (cell.getCellType() == org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                            columndata.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                        } else if (cell.getCellType() == org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {
                            columndata.add(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "");
                        }
                }
            }

            if (isHeader == false ) {
                rowdata.add(columndata); // to make sure we don't add an empty array for header row
            }
        }

        workbook.close();

        String[][] return_array = new String[rowdata.size()][];
        for (int i = 0; i < rowdata.size(); i++) {
            ArrayList<String> row = rowdata.get(i);
            return_array[i] = row.toArray(new String[row.size()]);
        }

        return return_array;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } 


}
```

And this, finally, is my test code

```
//My testclass

    package test;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
    import org.testng.Assert;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    import pgFactory.fb.HomePage;
    import pgFactory.fb.LandingPage;
    import pgFactory.fb.TimeLine;

    public class TestFaceBookUsingExcelSheetAsDataProvider {

        // Constructor to be called from factory class
        public TestFaceBookUsingExcelSheetAsDataProvider(String email, String password, String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.email = email;
            this.password = password;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        // class variables to be used in the tests
        WebDriver driver;
        LandingPage lp;
        HomePage hp;
        TimeLine tl;

        // Variables from data provider which in turn is reading from excel sheet
        private String email = null;
        private String password = null;
        private String firstName = null;
        private String lastName = null;

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return this.email+ " " + this.password + " " +  this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
        }

        @BeforeTest
        public void setup() {
            // Driver
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            // Pages
            lp = new LandingPage(driver).get();
            hp = new HomePage(driver).get();
            tl = new TimeLine(driver).get();

        }

        // Test methods

        @Test()
        public void testLogin() {
            lp.login(email, password);
            // Assert that after login you will see your home page
            Assert.assertEquals(hp.getUserLeftNavName().getAttribute("innerHTML"), firstName + " " + lastName,
                    "The full name is not correct on the left side user navigation frame");
            Assert.assertEquals(hp.getUserUpperNavName().getAttribute("innerHTML"), firstName,
                    "The first is not correct on the upper user navigation bar");

            hp.logOut();
        }

        @Test
        public void testMyPage() {
            lp.login(email, password);
            hp.getUserLeftNavName().click();
            String name = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 5))
                    .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("fb-timeline-cover-name"))).getText();
            Assert.assertEquals(name, firstName + " " + lastName, "The fullname on timeline cover is not correct");
            hp.logOut();
        }


        @AfterTest
        public void teardown() {
            driver.quit();
        }

    }
```

BTW, I am learning selenium by automating a few tests on facebook page. So, if I am making a silly mistake, please be patient with me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by debugging the code. The issue is when factory is used then I don't have any control over the BeforeTest annotated methods. These are not being run before tests start to execute. So, NPE is thrown because my pageObject is not instantiated yet.

Workaround. I annotated setup method with @Test and made other tests dependent on this test and it worked like a charm. Its not the best solution because now I have to make every existing and future tests with this dependsOnMethods parameter in annotation.

If you know of a better solution, please reply.

Comment: Now I am using BeforeClass instead of BeforeTest and I dont have to add test dependency. Working good.